# Python RDF lib - String value for nodes

Tags: python, rdf, rdflib

I am using RDF lib to retrieve values from an online triple store.

I was wondering whats the ideal way of turning URIRef and Literals to plain string objects?

For example :

```
value = g.value(s,FOAF.page)
```

Should I be using `value.n3()`, or `value.__str__()` ? Is there any difference ? On my tests, both return a sting that looks the same.

Initially I was just storing the value, but turns out it causes problems during String comparisons, so I would like to just store a string, as there is no rdf-related processing after the extraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the string contents of a literal, use `str(value)`. Note that this throws away some information -- the datatype and the language -- that are part of the RDF model.

For comparison:

```
lit = rdflib.term.Literal('Literal\nvalue', lang='en')

print(str(lit))
print('---')
print(lit.n3())
```

gives:

```
Literal
value
---
"""Literal
value"""@en
```

It sounds like you want the former.

See `pydoc3 rdflib.term.Literal.n3` for more detail on what the `n3()` method returns.